# Converting markdown text to ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, markdown

I have some (over 100) notes take down as mark down text file (with .md extension). Recently I discovered ipython notebook. Barring no Vim keybinding, it looks perfect. So would like to convert all those .md files into .ipynb files. Is there such a tool?

Comment: You are not going to get helpful answers from SO without showing what you've tried already.

Comment: @user590028 Tried it? Tried what? Googling it? Let's just say it was implied. I didn't say I googled it means I didn't google it? Or did you mean tried to write myself? Why would I do that? Enough with the "your question is so dump and I'm going to down vote you" attitude! SO has becoming more and more of an unpleasant place.

Comment: Take a look at [notedown](https://github.com/aaren/notedown) - "Markdown <=> IPython Notebook"

Answer (score 2):

Unless you find it through Google, unlikely. Notebook files are large JSON structures that can contain markdown in one or more discrete cells. For small cases, copy+paste are enough.